# upload image to wordpress library using local location

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I need to upload images to wordpress using location of the image on the drive like this :

"C:\Users\me\Pictures\1.jpg"

without using file dialog to choose the image file because I need to upload image using url and its location on the drive

how to mod the code below to do what I need

```
<?php
require('../wp-load.php');
require_once('../wp-admin/includes/image.php');
//==========================================
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="img_url">img_url</label>
    <input type="text" name="img_url" id="img_url" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>';
//==========================================
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $image_url = $_POST["img_url"]; 

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );

    $filename = basename( $image_url );

    if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
      $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    }
    else {
      $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    }

    file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
      'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
      'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
      'post_content' => '',
      'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );
    ECHO $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id);
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$UploadDir = wp_upload_dir();

$URL = $UploadDir['url']."/my_image.png"

echo $URL;

?>
```

Comment: do you mean to replace $upload_dir['path'] with $UploadDir['url'] ??